# Renderizado condicional de imagenes React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, component, jsx

Hola que tal me encuentro haciendo un proyecto escolar con React Native, el propósito de esta app es mostrar varias imagenes dependiendo el caso. Digamos que tengo que renderizar una imágen por nivel (hay n niveles), las imagenes están en el directorio del proyecto, pero no se como renderizarlas en forma de lista

( a cada nivel puede corresponderle cualquiera de 19 imagenes que tengo, por ejemplo al nivel 3 le puede corresponder la imagen 11. En cuanto a niveles no hay un límite)

les dejo un ejemplo de como me gustaría que se vea al final)
:

***EJEMPLO***

NIVEL 3:

renderiza imagen 2

NIVEL 2:

renderiza imagen 9

NIVEL 1:

renderiza imagen 4

etc...

Hasta ahora tengo una función para seleccionar la imagen que deseo renderizar dependiendo del nivel que es esta

```
function FnSelector(levelNumber) {

    switch (levelNumber) {
        case 0: return <Image source={ require('../../assets/0.png')}/>
        case 1: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/1.png')}/>
        case 2: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/2.png')}/>
        case 3: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/3.png')}/>
        case 4: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/4.png')}/>
        case 5: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/5.png')}/>
        case 6: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/6.png')}/>
        case 7: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/7.png')}/>
        case 8: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/8.png')}/>
        case 9: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/9.png')}/>
        case 10: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/10.png')}/>
        case 11: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/11.png')}/>
        case 12: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/12.png')}/>
        case 13: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/13.png')}/>
        case 14: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/14.png')}/>
        case 15: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/15.png')}/>
        case 16: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/16.png')}/>
        case 17: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/17.png')}/>
        case 18: return  <Image source={ require('../../assets/18.png')}/>
        case 19: return <Image source={ require('../../assets/19.png')}/>
    }
}
```

La idea sería que iterar esta función de la siguiente forma

```
let nivel = //aqui va un nivel máximo
for (let i = nivel; i > 0; i--) {
    FnSelector(i)
}
```

Pero hasta este punto no se como renderizar esa lista de imagenes que seleccione previamente en mi componente, les agradecería mucho su ayuda

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Se me ocurrió una forma usando UseState pero por alguna razón no renderiza las imagenes:

```
let levelNumber
const Representacion = () => {

    const [imagenes, setImagen] = useState([])

    for (let i = nivel; i > 0; i--) {
    
        levelNumber = allFactors(i, 1)
        switch (levelNumber) {
            case 0: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/0.png')); console.log('0');break;
            case 1: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/1.png'));console.log('1'); break;
            case 2: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/2.png'));console.log('2'); break;
            case 3: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/3.png'));console.log('3'); break;
            case 4: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/4.png'));console.log('4'); break;
            case 5: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/5.png'));console.log('5'); break;
            case 6: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/6.png'));console.log('6'); break;
            case 7: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/7.png'));console.log('7'); break;
            case 8: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/8.png'));console.log('8'); break;
            case 9: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/9.png'));console.log('9'); break;
            case 10: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/10.png'));console.log('10'); break;
            case 11: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/11.png'));console.log('11'); break;
            case 12: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/12.png'));console.log('12'); break;
            case 13: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/13.png'));console.log('13'); break;
            case 14: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/14.png'));console.log('14'); break;
            case 15: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/15.png'));console.log('15'); break;
            case 16: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/16.png'));console.log('16'); break;
            case 17: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/17.png'));console.log('17'); break;
            case 18: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/18.png'));console.log('18'); break;
            case 19: ()=> setImagen(require('../../assets/19.png'));console.log('19'); break;
        }
    }
    return (
        <View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            
            }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Hola</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <FlatList
                data={imagenes}
                numColumns={2}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={item}
                        style={{
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,

                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: "#c35547",
                            resizeMode: "contain",
                            margin: 6,
                        }}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>

    )
}
```

Comment: No me queda muy clara la pregunta... si el usuario tiene nivel 3, tu ciclo retornaria 3.png, luego 2.png, luego 1.png y luego 0.png... lo que no sabes es como renderizar esas imagenes?

Comment: @Pipe no realmente, a cada nivel puede corresponderle cualquiera de 19 imagenes que tengo, por ejemplo al nivel 3 le puede corresponder la imagen 11. En cuanto a niveles no hay un límite. Y si, lo que no se es como renderizar esas imagenes (que tienen un orde pseudoaleatorio)

Comment: No entendí muy bien lo del orden de las imagenes... pero si el problema es solo la renderizada, pues puedes meter esas imagenes en un array de componentes y luego renderizar el array (react puede renderizar un array de componentes), algo como: ```const componentes=[<componente/>, <componente />];``` y luego lo renderizas ```{ componentes }```